# ¿Cómo iterar sobre los elementos de varias listas con un mismo ciclo for?

Tags: python, bucle-for, scraping, lógica

Buen día tengo problema con los `for`. Estoy aprendiendo Python y no se si habrá una forma de lograr lo que busco.

Tengo tres listas con diferentes palabras. La primera la usare para igualar, la segunda la uso para hacer un `POST` a una pagina, y la tercera lista la uso para hacer scraping directamente.

Mi problema esta en que las tres listas tienen que estar en un `for` para se hagan todas en cola, sin tener que poner cada una manualmente.

Pensé que esto funcionaria pero descubrí que en realidad el segundo `for` repite las mismas veces dependiendo de los elementos que tenga la lista.

```
for i2 in b: #Hago la peticion
  b1 = i2
  urlr = "https://www.web.com/search"
  payloadr = {'q':b1} #peticion
  rz = requests.get(urlr, params=payloadr)
  soupr = BeautifulSoup(rz.content, 'html.parser')
  for i in a: #uso la primera lista para igualar con lo extraido
    k = soupr.find_all('a','Title')[0]
    if i == k.getText():
      print("se encontro 1")
    else:
      k = soupr.find_('a','Title')[1]
      if i == k.getText():
        print("se encontro 2")
      else:
        print("no se encontro")
```

Y si el segundo `for` lo saco del ciclo del primer `for` solo me igualara la ultima palabra de la lista `a`. Suponiendo que logro resolver ese problema, necesito hacerle un scraping al encontrar la variable y luego el mismo procedimiento. Hacer el `POST`, igualar lo extraido con la segunda palabra de la lista y usar la variable para scraping. Asi hasta terminar la lista. ¿Como podria resolver este problema?. Espero sea posible lograr lo que busco gracias!

Comment: A ver si entendí, quieres sacar un valor de cada lista, ejecutar el código con esos tres valores y volver a repetir el código con los siguientes valores?

Comment: Exacto, El `for` recorrerá todo los elementos  de la lista, Por lo cual repetira el mismo proceso con las demas palabras hasta terminar la lista. Pero no veo la forma de logarlo sin otra otro `for` para las demás listas

Comment: No creo que lo expliques bien. Si tienes `n` urls y `m` palabras para comprobar, y puede aparecer `p` veces en el texto, entonces tendrás que hacer `n * m * p` comprobaciones. No veo el problema de usar _bucles for anidados_. Supongo que tu problema es otro. Explica mejor lo de que tiene que estar en un único for _"para se hagan todas en cola, sin tener que poner cada una **manualmente**"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para iterar los elementos de varias listas a la vez en un mismo `for` puedes
usar la funcion `zip`. Lo que hace es juntar cada lista en un mismo "iterable"
que produce tuplas con los elementos de cada lista. Un ejemplo:

```
lista1 = [1, 2, 3]
lista2 = ["a", "b", "c"]
lista3 = ["azul", "verde", "rojo"]

for numero, letra, color in zip(lista1, lista2, lista3):
    print(numero, letra, color)
```

Salida:

```
1 a azul
2 b verde
3 c rojo
```

Answer (score 1):

Una forma menos Pythonica pero que se puede traducir fácilmente a cualquier lenguaje:

```
>>> lista1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> lista2 = ["one", "two", "three"]
>>> lista3 = ["uno", "dos", "tres"]
>>> i = 0
>>> while i<len(lista1):
...     print(lista1[i], lista2[i], lista3[i])
...     i += 1
... 
1 one uno
2 two dos
3 three tres
```